# Convert members of interface based dictionary to concrete based dictionary

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Given a dictionary comprised of Interface based keys and values what is the best way to convert/cast the dictionary to a dictionary with concrete based keys and values?

```
IDictionary<IKeyType, IList<IValueType>> myDict = new Dictionary<IKeyType,IList<IValueType>>();

IDictionary<KeyType, IList<ValueType>> newDict = myDict.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v = > v.Value.OfType<ValueType>());
```

Obviously the second line does not work in it's current form.

Can anyone suggest an efficient way of dealing with this problem?

Comment: Efficient way - don't do conversion and use interfaces. Otherwise please show working code so someone can improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do below. But if your code requires some casting from abstract type to its concrete implementation then you may have some other problems with your design.

```
Dictionary<KeyType, IList<ValueType>> newDict = 
                   myDict.ToDictionary(
                       k => k.Key as KeyType, 
                       v => v.Value.OfType<ValueType>() as IList<ValueType>);
```